# How to start application from another app in Android using Action_SEND?

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, android-manifest, send

I'm trying to get my app to display in the "Open in app" dialog when I open a PDF file. I believe on paper I should be done:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.foo.anything">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" /> -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

But it just doesn't show up. I am using my phone as test device, could that be a factor?
I've been looking for answers for 2 hours now, please help.

Comment: "when I open a PDF file" -- "open" is a verb that I usually associate with `ACTION_VIEW`. `ACTION_SEND`, which you are using now, is for "share" sorts of operations.

Comment: I think this is what you need. I haven't used this recently, so I don't really have any details to give, but basically it's used to tell other apps that your app can handle certain types of data.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics

Comment: Also try this.
https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm using ACTION_SEND, so that should be correct? I am not going to display anything on screen, I just need a way to pass the pdf to my application and run an activity without GUI.

Comment: "I'm using ACTION_SEND, so that should be correct?" -- are saying that you have written two apps, one that is the sender via `ACTION_SEND` and one (shown above) that is the intended recipient? If so, then perhaps the problem is with your sending code.